# Return Rows, when two conditions that are true

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012

The following query works fine in returning data as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(varchar, b.bookindt, 101) AS [book-in date],
    b.bookinno AS [book-in no.],
    dbo.fn_getoffensedesc(o.offenseid, o.probviolation,
                          (select offense from trdcode61 
                           where code61id = o.code61id), o.goc) AS offensedescription,
    o.PrimaryOffense AS [Primary Offense],
    trd.l_d AS [offense l/d],
    p.firstname AS [first name],
    p.lastname AS [last name]
FROM
    tblpeople p
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tbloffense o (NOLOCK) ON o.personid = p.personid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblbookin b (NOLOCK) ON b.bookinid = o.bookinid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    trdcode61 trd (NOLOCK) ON trd.code61id = o.code61id 
WHERE
    dbo.fn_isinjailbybookinid(b.bookinid) = 1 
    -- AND b.bookinno='21042173'
    AND (trd.l_d LIKE 'F%' OR trd.l_d LIKE 'M%')
ORDER BY
    p.lastname, p.firstname
```

Here is a screenshot of results for a single "bookinno" to be clearer:

[image]

I need help with a query, where it looks at the "Book-in No." column AND if the "Offense l/d" column includes an `(trd.l_d like 'F%' AND trd.l_d like 'M%')` then return that "Book-in No." result.

When I try to run with `AND` I get zero results.

I do have "Book-in No." with only "F%" or only "M%".

Would appreciate any help.

Regards,
jer

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). But if you do and understand the risk, AT LEAST use current syntax, not deprecated syntax.

Comment: your query look ok to me with `where  b.bookinno='21042173' and (trd.l_d like 'F%' or trd.l_d like 'M%')` .I doubt this is not working `dbo.fn_isinjailbybookinid(b.bookinid) = 1 `

Comment: @SMor, what is latest syntax for nolock ?

Comment: Using GROUP BY without aggregates has a bad smell. But perhaps the column trd.l_d does not contain what you assume. Cast that column to varbinary(20) to see what it actually contains.

Comment: If you "must" have the `GROUP BY` use `DISTINCT` instead; it makes no sense to group when you have no aggregation.

Comment: My query works fine without the "Group By" section. Yes, "Distinct", works fine too. Thanks for the feedback. @SMOR, like KumarHarsh asked, what is the latest syntax for nolock? Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't return any hits: where
dbo.fn_isinjailbybookinid(b.bookinid) = 1 
and
(trd.l_d like 'F%' and trd.l_d like 'M%')

Comment: This query is a litany of bad practices: `NOLOCK` should not be used *at all* except in specific circumstances. `LEFT JOIN` which are actually `INNER` because of `WHERE` clauses. `varchar` conversion without a length can cause truncation. Converting to `varchar` rather than `date` to truncate time component is inefficient. Scalar UDFs are very bad for performance, especially in the `WHERE`. Column names that need quoting get annoying quickly

Comment: @Charlieface, bless your heart! Thank you for your feedback, have a Happy Holiday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the resultset with your conditions, group by `bookinno` and set the condition in the HAVING clause so that both conditions apply to that `bookinno`:

```
SELECT b.bookinno AS [book-in no.]
FROM tblpeople p
INNER JOIN tbloffense o ON o.personid = p.personid 
INNER JOIN tblbookin b ON b.bookinid = o.bookinid 
INNER JOIN trdcode61 trd ON trd.code61id = o.code61id 
WHERE dbo.fn_isinjailbybookinid(b.bookinid) = 1 
  AND (trd.l_d LIKE 'F%' OR trd.l_d LIKE 'M%')
GROUP BY b.bookinno
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(trd.l_d, 1)) = 2;
```

Note that the joins for this requirement should be `INNER` and not `LEFT` because you don't want in the results any unmatched rows.

Comment: thanks for your reply and code. However; I need for it to look at the b.bookino AND if these two conditions are true (trd.l_d LIKE 'F%' AND trd.l_d LIKE 'M%'), return that b.bookino. Thanks

Comment: @jr7138 this is what the query does. If you want results for a specific bookino then add to the WHERE clause:  `AND bookino = '21042173'`

Comment: Yes, I agree. But, I need for the code to look at a b.bookinno "and" then look at trd.l_d AND if that b.bookinno has both an ("F% AND "M%") return that b.bookinno.

Comment: @jr7138 did you try the code? The group by and the having clauses do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: yes. But, it's still not the result I need. Let me drop some code and screenshot to show you. Oops, can't do that.

Comment: @jr7138 if this is not the result that you want then you did not explain correctly what you want.

Comment: went to lunch and with a fresh mind was able to get the data using your SQL. Thank you for all your help.